# Styling Greek text with polutonikogreek to fit with Times

Tags: fonts, greek, times

Does someone know how to change the font of `polutonikogreek` `babel` so that it fits Times font that I use for main text better? I am open to suggestions what would fit the best, because I have no idea what is available.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,ngerman]{babel}%
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{mathptmx}% Times font
\newcommand{\grk}[1]{{\foreignlanguage{polutonikogreek}{#1}}}% GREEK TEXT
\begin{document}
\section{\grk{<Omoo'usios} – Der gottgleiche Sohn}
\blindtext
\begin{quote}\grk{o>uko~un t~w m`en >agenn'htw patr`i o>ike~ion >ax'iwma fulakt'eon, mhd'ena to~u e@inai a>ut~w t`on a>'ition l'egontas; t~w d`e u<i~w t`hn <arm'ozousan tim`hn >aponemht'eon, t`hn >'anarqon a>ut~w par`a to~u patr`os g'ennhsin >anatij'entas; ka`i <ws >efj'asamen a>ut~w s'ebas >apon'emontes, m'onon e>usebos ka`i e>uf'hmws t`o @hn ka`i t`o >ae`i ka`i t`o pr`o a>i'wnwn l'egontes >ep> a>uto~u, t`hn m'entoi je'othta a>uto~u m`h paraito'umenoi, >all`a t~h e>ik'oni ka`i t~w qarakt~hri to~u patr`os >aphkribwm'enhn >emf'ereian kat`a p'anta >anatij'entes, t`o d`e >ag'ennhton t~w patr`i m'onon >id'iwma pare~inai dox'azontes, <'ate d`h ka`i a>uto~u f'askontos to~u swt~hros; »<o pat'hr mou me'izwn mo'u >estin«.}\end{quote}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since your document is utf8-encoded, is there a reason for not providing the Greek input in "native" polytonic letters?

Comment: Yes native Greek letters fit well with default Latex Font (Computer Modern) but do not fit well with Times font, requested by my publisher.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Tempora, that supports ancient Greek.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <--- don't forget
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tempora}% Times font
\usepackage{newtxmath}% if you need math

\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\grk}[1]{{\foreignlanguage{polutonikogreek}{#1}}}% GREEK TEXT

\newenvironment{greekquote}
 {\begin{quote}\begin{otherlanguage*}{polutonikogreek}}
 {\end{otherlanguage*}\end{quote}}

\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\blindtext
\begin{greekquote}
o>uko~un t~w m`en >agenn'htw patr`i o>ike~ion >ax'iwma fulakt'eon,
mhd'ena to~u e@inai a>ut~w t`on a>'ition l'egontas; t~w d`e u<i~w 
t`hn <arm'ozousan tim`hn >aponemht'eon, t`hn >'anarqon a>ut~w par`a
to~u patr`os g'ennhsin >anatij'entas; ka`i <ws >efj'asamen a>ut~w 
s'ebas >apon'emontes, m'onon e>usebos ka`i e>uf'hmws t`o @hn ka`i 
t`o >ae`i ka`i t`o pr`o a>i'wnwn l'egontes >ep> a>uto~u, t`hn m'entoi 
je'othta a>uto~u m`h paraito'umenoi, >all`a t~h e>ik'oni ka`i t~w 
qarakt~hri to~u patr`os >aphkribwm'enhn >emf'ereian kat`a p'anta 
>anatij'entes, t`o d`e >ag'ennhton t~w patr`i m'onon >id'iwma 
pare~inai dox'azontes, <'ate d`h ka`i a>uto~u f'askontos to~u 
swt~hros; »<o pat'hr mou me'izwn mo'u >estin«.
\end{greekquote}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want small caps for the Latin alphabet, change the preamble as follows. I don't think you can get small caps Greek.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <--- don't forget
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{newtxtext}% Times font
\usepackage{newtxmath}% if you need math
\usepackage{substitutefont}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\substitutefont{LGR}{\familydefault}{Tempora-TLF}
```

Comment: Tempora unfortunately has no small caps! :(

Comment: @eklisiarh I added a workaround for getting small caps in the Latin alphabet.

Comment: The second solution you offered clashes with some packages I use like `textcomp` (I edited my MWE to include that package too now because I could not anticipate that this will be a problem). Another thing is this doesnt work for Greek text in the title. It also gives me error `No declaration for shape LGR/Tempora-TLF/m/sc.`. I don't want to waste any more of your time. Maybe someone else has some different solution than changing `mathptmx` package with something else, because that package works great for me (except the greek font).

Comment: @eklisiarh You should load `textcomp` after `newtxtext`; for the error about `LGR/Tempora-TLF/m/sc`, I wrote that there are small caps only for the Latin alphabet. Are small caps used for ancient Greek?

Comment: Ok thanks. Loading `textcomp`after `newtxtext`solved package clash problem. As for small caps they are not used in ancient Greek but when I use Greek word in the title this causes a problem because my titles are all small caps so Latex tries changing Greek to small caps too. Maybe I should ask separate question where I include styling in my MWE? Or should I edit my question to also include that?  Also formatting in the title is still not correct and has different style than Greek in text.